# catching new exception in Application Insights

Tags: azure-application-insights

How can I do the following in Application Insights

1.) catch a new exception which never occurred before in Application insights and send an email alert.

2.) How can I catch a specific exception e.g "Error connecting to server" and send an email alert

Answer (score 0):

Write some code in your app to catch the exception and look at/set a flag to see if it happened recently. If it didn't, send a [TrackException() call](https://azure.microsoft.com/documentation/articles/app-insights-api-custom-events-metrics/#track-exception) with a [custom metric](https://azure.microsoft.com/documentation/articles/app-insights-api-custom-events-metrics/#properties) set to a high value. Then in the portal, set an alert on that metric. (At present you can't set metrics on individual events.)